# Difference between GET and POST in HTTP

Tags: php, http, vbscript

There are some posts about the difference between `POST` and `GET`, but my problem is more specific, here it is:

I can use GET to send and get data from the server using this VBScript example:

```
Send "https://www.server.com/send.php"
Sub Send(url)
    Dim objHTTP, MyResponse
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )
    objHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    objHTTP.Send "One Plus One"
    MsgBox objHTTP.ResponseText()
End Sub
```

But this same example works if I change `GET` with `POST`, so:

1. What's the difference?
2. What should I use when I want to send and receive data at the same time?

And this is my **PHP** code on the server if you're interested:

```
<?php
$stdin = fopen('php://input', 'r');

$Data = '';
while (!feof($stdin))
  $Data .= fread($stdin, 8192);

$Data .= " Equals Two";

echo $Data;
?>
```

Note that I didn't mention HTML, because my code has nothing to do with it, but if the difference has to do with HTML, I would be happy to know about it.

Comment: @Sanu0786 fWhat I understood from this post is that, there is no functional difference, it's just how the data is treated when it arrives to the server, If I save it in a file for example (changing the server state) I should use `POST`, In the example above I've just echoed text (no change in the state) so I should use `GET`, is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `POST` request has a body, this body carries the information you are trying to send with the request, and the main advantage of `POST` is that this data can be quite lengthy, you can even send files.

`GET` does not have a body, if you want to send any data it has to be carried in the Query String, which is basically the stuff that goes after the `?` in the URL. Example:

```
https://google.com/?q=this+is+the+data
```

As the data goes in the URL, you cant really put whatever you want there. Most browsers and servers will limit the maximum URL size to something in the order of a few kilobytes, and it is not very useful at all if you intent to post long texts or files.

Comment: Your answer is crystal clear, thank's.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to send and receive data, you must have used the POST method to send data to the server that will process this data and return a result, this result can be displayed directly on the interface or saved in a file for the user. used later. the most practical method is to use JSON. for the result to be saved as a temporary file or in a * .json file.